# Question about a proof in Nievergelt's Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

There, above the blue line, why $u(z) \to 0$ as $|z| \to r$ ? I understand that $\theta (z) \to \infty$ but from where we can conclude that $|f'(z)|$ or $\lambda(f(z))$ doesn't go to $\infty$ when $|z| \to r$ ? Thanks!

Edit:
Oh. Ok. I think I got it. Because $0 < r < R$ I can take $\overline{D_r} \subset D_R$ which is compact. then $f'(\overline{D_r})$ is bounded because of continuity of $f'$ and $\lambda(f(\overline{D_r}))$ is bounded because of continuity of $f$ and $\lambda$, and because $D_r \subset \overline{D_r} \implies \lambda(f(D_r))$ and $f'(D_r)$ are bounded too, so the limit is $0$ indeed. Is ok now?

Edit2: But... 1 line below: how can $u(a) \in D_r$ ? Because by Maximum Modulus Principle it can't be possible

Comment: What is $\Delta^c$?

Comment: $\Delta^c u = \frac{1}{4} \Delta u = \frac{1}{4} (\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}) = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z \partial \overline{z}}$

Comment: I've made an edit. It's ok now?

Comment: $u$ is not analytic, just continuous, so it has a maximum in $\bar D_r$, but that maximum cannot be on the boundary because $u>0$ inside and goes to zero at the boundary

Comment: @Conrad thanks! I understand now. But you can explain me why $log(u)$ is $C^2$ ? Thanks you!

Comment: $|f'|^2=f' \bar f'$ is real analytic (so smooth) since for an analytic function, its conjugate $\bar f'$ is anti-analytic, hence harmonic hence real analytic, $\theta_r$ is also smooth by inspection and $\lambda$ is $C^2$ so $u$ is $C^2$ and since it is not zero near $a$, $\log u$ is also $C^2$ there

Comment: And image of $C^k$ function through $\log$ is a $C^k$ function?

Comment: as long as $\log$ is well defined (eg we take $\log$ of positive numbers), it is smooth, so preserves whatever smoothness $f$ has

Comment: @Conrad thanks you for all. I really try to understand this proof. But how they calculate $\Delta^c(\log u)(a)$? Ok.. $\log$ is holomorphic and we can calculate complex laplacian but why we can calculate complex laplacian for $\lambda$ for example if we dont know if it is holomorphic?

Comment: the laplacian makes sense for any $C^2$ function as it involves just partial derivatives up to order $2$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149047/discussion-between-mathlearner-and-conrad).

Comment: @Conrad can you see what I've written on chat please?